# How can I use appsettings variables in web.config use again in web.config

Tags: asp.net

My web.config is like below. I want to use appsettings variables different row in web.config. Is it possible and if possible, how can I do ?

Edit for Detail: I have 10+ server and they use same web application. Their ip list is different for each other . I am using MicrosoftConfigurationBuilders for get variables from Environmet Variables. I can get values from environment but i dont know how can i replace value in IPFILTER tag with it.

```
<configuration>
        <appSettings>
            <add key="MyIp1" value="198.162.1.1"/>
            <add key="MyIp2" value="198.162.1.2"/>
        </appSettings>
    </configuration>
     <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="MyService1">
              <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
              <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
              <IPFilter filter="{MyIp1}" />
            </behavior>
            <behavior name="MyService2">
              <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
              <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
              <IPFilter filter="{MyIp2}" />
            </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
```

Comment: What's your goal?

Comment: I have 10+ server and they use same web application. Their ip filter list is different for each other . I am using MicrosoftConfigurationBuilders for get variables from Environmet Variables. I can get values from environment but i dont know how can i replace value in IPFILTER tag with it.

Comment: Why do not you write IP values into filter property?

Comment: If i do, every server has unique web.config file. I want to deploy all server(10+) same web.config. These ip values should be dynamic.